# Persistant Local Storage iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, html, cordova

I am developing a mobile app and I hoped to use HTML5 Persistant Storage. I have read though that iOS 5.1+ doesn't support it as it removes it periodically.

Is there a solution or fix to this? I am using Phonegap/Apache Cordova.

Thanks.

Comment: Where have you read that? It sounds wrong.

Comment: http://www.itwriting.com/blog/5656-apple-breaks-web-storage-in-ios-5-1-does-not-care-about-web-apps.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in recent PhoneGap installs. If you are using the latest version, you should be fine.